# Подсветить второй элемент

Tags: pure_js, html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть простой список:

```
<ul class="spisok">
<li><span>Текст</span></li>
<li><span>Текст</span></li>
<li><span>Текст</span></li>
<li><span>Текст</span></li>
</ul>
```

Как добавить ко второму элементу "li" красный цвет к тексту, учитывая что добавлять классы можно либо всем либо некому.

Comment: А что за метка завелась такая - `[pure_js]`?

Comment: Метка, акцентирующая внимание на том, что решение ожидается на "чистом" JS.

Comment: метка для `jQuery-фобов`

Comment: А `[javascript]` тогда зачем? Надо просто чрезмерно расплодившихся резигов посыпать дустом. Помните, что сказал Оккам, когда порезался во время бритья?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
 li:nth-child(2) {color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Вот, прям, ТОЧНО, ОДИН в ОДИН ваш вопрос. И цвет даже красный.

```
$('li.spisok').eq(1).css('background-color', 'red');//вот с номером тока ошиблись. На единицу.
```

---

```
var classOfUl = 'spisok';
var WhichLi = 2;

var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for(var i=0;i<uls.count;i++){
  if(uls[i].className==classOfUl){
    var lis = uls.getElementsByTagName('li');
    lis[(WhichLi-1)].style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

Comment: А без Jquery можно? у меня на чужом проекте либа mootools подключена, и соответственно все плагины через неё

Comment: А зачем, простите, вы в метках jquery указали? =)

Comment: я спутал, нету метку переправил)

Comment: Для таких случаев я специальную метку создал. =(

Comment: Я Извиняюсь, и еще за то что выберу ответ с CSS, он по короче) Спасибо за отзывы.

Comment: Не надо извиняться=) Если он вам больше подходит, его и берите!

Answer (score 0):

`ul li:first-child+li`

Вроде так.